# BibTeX with Plain TeX

Tags: bibtex, plain-tex

The manpage of `bibtex` says that it can be used with both LaTeX and TeX. However, I did not find any resource how to do it and also no TeX book of mine explains it. Can someone provide a minimalistic example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at the `btxmac.tex` from [Eplain](http://tug.org/eplain/) (usually found in `texmf-dist/tex/eplain`). It includes an example of use with plain TeX.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the example given in http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/patashnik.pdf:

```
\input btxmac

The \TeX{}book~\cite{knuth:tex} is good.
\medskip

\leftline{\bf References}

\bibliography{mybib}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bye
```

There is nothing really special.

Answer (score 0):

The [eplain manual](http://tug.org/eplain/doc/eplain.html#Citations) describes how to use bibtex with some of the eplain commands. It looks *really* similar to the way it's done in LaTeX.

Comment: Could you provide a working example?